# Typescript method not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I have an Import/Export functionality.

Here is my cshtml code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#importPopup').dialog('open');return false;"><img src="import.png" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Importfrom file" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" /></a>

<a href="#" onclick="return false;" ng-click="myViewModel.ExportFile()"><img src="export.png" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Export to file" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" /></a>

<div id="importPopup" title="Import">
    <p><input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" /></p>
    <p><input type="button" class="_button" value="Import File" ng-click="myViewModel.ImportFile()" /></p>
</div>
```

Now I have two functions on my typescript code.

```
public ImportFile() {
    // some codes here
}

public ExportFile() {
    // some codes here
}
```

My problem here is my `ImportFile` function is not being hit. I tried to put two breakpoints on both of them, and the `ExportFile` is working but not the `ImportFile`.

What did I missed here?

Comment: is there any error in your web console?

Comment: No, I can't find anything on my console.

Comment: can you check the genereated js file to see the difference of this two method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is `$('#importPopup').dialog('open');`. This means that the html is rendered by bootstrap and doesn't go through the angular `$compile` process. Hence `ng-click` isn't setup.

## Fix

Use something like Angular-BootStrap-Modal : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: Thank you for this! I was able to make it work. I made my `importPopup` a modal and it is working now.